# Splitting string on new line after third float - Python

Tags: python, string, list, split

I'm trying to get a single string split into different lines.

I have the following single line string:

```
h = 
John_______________7.3 7.9 9.7 Peter-Pan__________5.1 6.3 6.6 
Steve Stevenson____5.1 5.3 5.5 Johnny Palmer______8.3 8.8 9.2 
Randy______________8.0 8.0 8.0
```

And i'm trying to get this output:

```
h = 
John_______________7.3 7.9 9.7 
Peter-Pan__________5.1 6.3 6.6 
Steve Stevenson____5.1 5.3 5.5 
Johnny Palmer______8.3 8.8 9.2
Randy______________8.0 8.0 8.0

Where when i select h[0] the output should be:
John
Peter-Pan
Steve Stevenson
Johnny Palmer
Randy
```

I have already written code to work with the info if it's in the above format
I've tried for hours many different things but couldn't succeed. This let me to try to write new code to work with the info as it is right now instead.

I show my current code with that intention but it might not be relevant if the desired output is possible.

In the code I am trying to split a string on every name and three floats in a row. My current code now, though different from many other tries, isolates every three grades in a single item in a list and isolates the names as single items, but splits the names where they should not. I can't use iter, map and zip again since it's different with every name:

```
replacechar = h.replace(' ', '_')
student_list = replacechar.split('_')
isolated_grades = [item for item in student_list if 
                   item.strip('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_-0123456789') == '.']
isolated_names = [item for item in student_list if not 
                  item.strip('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz_-0123456789') == '.']
isolated_names2 = ' '.join(isolated_names)
isolated_names3 = isolated_names2.split()
i = iter(isolated_grades)
f = map(" ".join, zip(i, i, i))
```

I tried splitting on delimeters like spaces or '_'. I tried replacing characters in order to split and tried defining every item based on .isalpha or .isdigit. However i cannot succeed since every name is of different length of words and might or might not contain spaces or dashes. Also the first float is connected with the name trough underscores. My brain is overloaded
Right now my goal is getting every person with grades on a new line which would allow me to select the names and grades:

Comment: can you guarantee that no name includes a '_'

Comment: yes (achieving minimal character limit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use regular expressions, which provide pattern matching.  An regular expression of `'[A-Za-z -]+_+[0-9. ]+'` should match the name, underscore, scores pattern.  Then, `re.findall('[A-Za-z -]+_+[0-9. ]+', string)` will return the list of strings.  You can combine this back into a newline seperated string with `'\n'.join(list_of_results)`.

Python regular expression documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Comment: exactly what I would have done - but i wouldn't have been able to write the regex that quickly.

Comment: You don't need to escape the dash in your character classes if it's the last character listed: `[A-Za-z -]`

Comment: Sorry I'm revising my question due to a realization. Question remains somewhat the same though problem can be solved if the desired output can be achieved

Comment: That actually simplifies things a little bit.  I updated my answer for the revision.

Comment: @JonahBishop Thanks, I'm never sure on the exact cases where the backslash can be skipped.

Comment: Solved it finally! had to add some for loops and change some stuff but your solution made it possible thanks!!